# Sum minutes and get hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to sum minutes up in Excel, and show the resulting hours.

Currently if for example, I sum 0.45 + 0.45, I get 90.

I should get 1.30.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are you getting 1.30 from 0.45 + 0.45?  Can you explain what these values mean?

Comment: @Idle_Mind 45 minutes + 45 minutes is an hour and a half

Comment: @Tom...right, but these are expressed as decimals, not minutes with a colon; 0.45 hours = 27 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need [TimeSerial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws25fd2z(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    MsgBox TimeSerial(0, 45 + 45, 0)
End Sub
```